# How does ARC work in loops?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I search a lot of information but couldn't find anything. Maybe I can't search well) As I know ARC work like compile tool. This tool actually instead of developer sets release and retains in assembler code. But my questions is how it will work if, for example, we create objects in loop of random value?

```
int value = arc4random_uniform(74);
for(int i=0; i<value; ++i) {
   MyObject* my = [MyObject new];
}
```

So how it will be resolved, because on compile time we don't know count of objects. If it works like after `MyObject* my = [MyObject new];` arc just add  `[my release];` why we should use autoreleasepool if it will be released at the moment???

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. Each time through the loop, the `my` object will be created and then immediately destroyed.

Comment: Autoreleasepool in ARC is needed only for returning object from methods by pointer at pointer, for example for errors: `NSError * __autoreleasing *`

Comment: `MyObject my = [MyObject new];` wouldn't even compile. At least take to the time to create some real code.

Comment: @Cy-4AH That’s not the only case where autorelease objects are created.

Comment: @Rob, yes, they may be created in many cases, but now I am talking about one and the only case when you should use `__autoreleasing` in ARC

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the whims of the compiler and it may change depending on targeted architecture, OS version and/or compiler optimization settings.

The # of passes through the loop doesn't matter.

Effectively, this:

```
for(int i=0; i<value; ++i) {
   MyObject* my = [MyObject new];
}
```

Might be compiled as:

```
for(int i=0; i<value; ++i) {
   MyObject* my = [[MyObject new] autorelease];
}
```

Or this:

```
for(int i=0; i<value; ++i) {
   MyObject* my = [MyObject new];
   [my release];
}
```

Both are perfectly valid.

Through profiling, you might find you need to surround a `for()` loop's body with `@autoreleasepool {}` if there is a ton of autorelease noise being generated by the loop.   Maybe.   Generally, though, a ton of autorelease pool traffic is indicative of an algorithmic problem.   Optimizing away memory thrash is oft critical to performance.

Answer (score 0):

You said

> As I know ARC work like compile tool. ... So how [will autorelease objects] be resolved, because on compile time we don't know count of objects.

ARC is a compile time tool, but autorelease objects aren't managed by ARC. They're managed by the autorelease pool, which is handled at runtime. So, as autorelease objects are created, they're added to the current pool, and when the pool is drained (either by yielding back to the OS or by creating your own manual autorelease pools) those autorelease references are released.

> why we should use autoreleasepool if it will be released at the moment???

By definition, autoreleased objects are *not* released at the moment. They're only released when the pool is drained.

As the compiler and ARC have evolved, it's gotten increasingly sophisticated about not creating autorelease objects, but rather creating objects that ARC will manage for you. You seem to be assuming that your code snippet will generate autorelease objects, but as bbum said, you have no such assurances. It's most likely managed by ARC, not the autorelease pool.

I would suggest profiling your app through the "Allocations" tool of "Instruments" and watching the memory usage there. If you see unbridled memory growth there which is only resolved when the loop finished, then you might have autorelease objects involved and putting an autorelease pool in your loop might be warranted. Otherwise, don't worry about it, as it's increasingly likely that no autorelease objects are involved.

Answer (score 0):

ARC is not magic. It's complicated, but it's not magic.

Let's look at your example

```
int value = arc4random_uniform(74);
for(int i=0; i<value; ++i) {
   MyObject* my = [MyObject new];
}
```

Assuming `MyObject` is based on `NSObject` and has not been overridden with a different return value, then we need to check the declaration of `new` in `NSObject`.

```
+ (instancetype)new OBJC_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE("use object initializers instead");
```

NOTE: No ARC declaration is made.

The default ARC setting is used, because there is no ARC declaration.

So the next question is, "what is the default?" Now we check the documenation: [Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).

> Methods in the `alloc`, `copy`, `init`, `mutableCopy`, and `new` families are implicitly marked `__attribute__((ns_returns_retained))`. This may be suppressed by explicitly marking the method `__attribute__((ns_returns_not_retained))`.

`-new` is in the `new` family, so the default is to have `__attribute__((ns_returns_retained))`.

`MyObject` will return retain +1 and will not be auto-released.

```
int value = arc4random_uniform(74);
for(int i=0; i<value; ++i) {
   MyObject* my = [MyObject new]/* Implied [my retain] */;
/* Implied [my release] */}
```

Comment: Maybe on the autorelease part;   versions of the compiler would have generated an autorelease on the returned object.   I.e. effectively `new` was `return [[[Klass alloc] init] autorelease];`.  I think that is largely no longer true, but it may be on some variants of DEBUG builds.   I *think* the compiler only generates checks to eliminate the `autorelease` on optimized builds, but I haven't looked in a long time and it likely changed.

Comment: @bbum If the compiler was doing it, then it violated the documented behavior. This has been the documented behavior since ARC was created.

Comment: @bbum For a method to return autorelease, it need to be attributed `__attribute__((ns_returns_autoreleased))`.

Comment: If you mark it as `ns_returns_autoreleased`, then the returned object will be in the autorelease pool.  When calling into ARC'd code from non-ARC'd code, the compiler generates the autorelease, too.  However, ARC calling into ARC will avoid the autorelease pool when possible. This is explained in section 3.2.3 here https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html.  And it changes over time.   In fact, it may have changed since the last time I looked which was a while ago as I haven't had to deal with MRR code in quite a while!

Comment: @bbum The optimization you pointed out only works one way. It can optimize away `ns_returns_autoreleased` in some special circumstances. There is no such provision for `ns_returns_not_retained`.